# RSPEC ERROR: assigns equals nil (compared using == )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

I am new to testing controllers with RSPEC. Currently I am testing to see if my assignment is correct. My controller action (what I am attempting to test) looks like this:

```
  def jobs
    @jobs = @customer.jobs
  end
```

My test looks like so:

```
describe CustomersController do
  before do 
    @company = FactoryGirl.create(:company_complete)
    @account = FactoryGirl.create(:account_house_address)
  end

it "assigns @jobs" do 
   get :jobs
    customer = FactoryGirl.create(:customer_john_human)
    job = FactoryGirl.create(:job_complete_job, account_id: @account.id, company_id: @company.id, customer_id: customer.id )

    expect(assigns(:jobs)).to eq([customer.jobs])
end
```

However when I run this i get the error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:jobs)).to eq([customer.jobs])

expected: [#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Job id: 1, name: nil, status: "pending", company_id: 1, account_id_old: nil, job_type_id: nil, address_id: nil, trade_id: 1, lead_id: nil, started_date: nil, end_date: nil, created_at: "2015-04-17 03:58:42", updated_at: "2015-04-17 03:58:42", order_number: 2, creator_id: nil, account_id: 1, customer_id: 1, contact_id: nil>]>]

got: nil
```

My full customers controller looks like this:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_member!
  load_and_authorize_resource
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end
  before_action :set_section
  before_action :set_client_form, except: [:index]
  before_action :set_customer, only: [:show, :jobs, :notes, :destroy]

  helper_method :selected_show_tab

  def index
    #got rid of this to make it easier to read :p
  end

  def jobs
    @jobs = @customer.jobs
  end
```

EDIT: i added the following case to authenticate the user:

```
before :each do
    controller.stub(:authenticate_member!)
end
```

However, i still get the same result :(

Comment: You didn't authenticate your `get` call, so most likely you `job` action has never been executed (as you were redirected to the login page)

Comment: how do i go about doing that

Comment: You have to stub all before filters so that action will get executed.